# Как сделать рассылку на 30к зарегистрированных пользователей, чтоб не приняли за спам?

Tags: php, хостинг

Как сделать сабж, чтоб хостер не локнул, ip  не попал в спамхаус, и чтобы письма дошли?

Answer (score 2):

1. Слать надо через какой-то грид, чтобы ip отправителей было как можно больше. Например, зарегиться в Amazon Web Services, см. их [SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/);
2. для домена настроить SPF и DKIM и письма подписывать;
3. в заголовки дописать List-Unsubscribe заголовки и обрабатывать приходящие ответы. Гугл напр. пытается так отписывать, когда жмут "Спам";
4. У mail.ru есть [сервис для постмастеров](http://help.mail.ru/mail-help/postmaster/postservice), следить за жалобами на письма с вашего домена;
5. Чем большее время займёт рассылка, тем меньше риск. За месяц, это по 1000 в день, по 42 в час — вполне нормально и для рассылки с одного адреса, если база адресов не куплена на рынке.

Answer (score 1):

Локнет обязательно.
Узнайте у провайдера сколько писем в единицу времени можно отправить и создайте очередь по крону, например.

Надо вам сказать, что крайне мала вероятность того, что вам нужно отправить именно 30к писем и это не спам. :) Если таковое все-таки случилось, значит проект давно перерос тот хостинг, на котором он сидит.

Comment: Проекту уже много лет, потому зарегано много юзеров. Но посещают понятное дело не все. Планирую сделать нововведения, и уведомить юзеров по мылу, ожидая скачок посещаемости. Спам-не спам, как хотите, так называйте.
За информацию спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Ну отправлять не все сразу.

И как на счет прокси?

Если несколько серверов, то вообще все кул.

Или вариант - зарегистрируй дешевый хостинг и проверь.